# MVC RedirectToAction not working in Azure emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

When running my MVC 3 project in using the azure emulator, I use this method call to redirect the browser to another URL:

```
int id = 4; // could be any number
return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id, area = "App" });
```

The emulated load balancer is running on port 81, and the actual website is in IIS on port 82.

When I run this, it redirects the browser to port 82... and I get a **400 - Bad Request - Invalid Hostname**.

I tried doing this... but it didn't help either:

```
var url = this.Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id, area = "App" });
return this.Redirect(url);
```

Even passing a relative URL to the `Redirect` method won't help... I used fiddler, and discovered that the redirect URL was not relative, and in fact the response from the server contained a full redirect URL pointing to port 82.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one? It's vexing me also - I get the error in MVC4 using an umbraco redirect after Http Post. It works in production though... strange.

Comment: No... I ended using `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpsIn"].IPEndpoint.Port` to build the URL with the correct port number.